# Lightning Datatable - href

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I am using a Lightning component that creates a lightning datatable and fills the rows and columns with values get by calling an Apex Class. I want in every line, in one column to use href. For the time being, i use a column type url but when clicking it opens  another window whereas i need to redirect the current browser window. Any ideas?
Code that i have used: please focus on

```
component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Customer Code at source system', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {
                label: {
                    fieldName: 'CustCode'
                }, 
and on: var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
                returnValue.forEach(function(record) {
                record.linkName = 'mydomainLink/'+record.CRMCustId+'/view';
            });
```

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.spinner", true);
        //ggalaios 2019-10-08 Create the Columns of Lightning Datatable
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Customer Code at source system', fieldName: 'linkName', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {
                label: {
                    fieldName: 'CustCode'
                },
                target: '_blank'
            }},
            {label: 'Customer Role Description', fieldName: 'CustRoleDsc', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Source system', fieldName: 'System_x', type: 'text'},
        ]);
        //03/10/2019: George Galaios: Call Apex Function to call EA Web Service for Parties
        var parties = component.get("c.getParties");          
        parties.setParams({
            //03/10/2019: George Galaios: Set parameters for Apex Function
            "searchDT" : component.get("v.searchDT"),
            "searchLob" : component.get("v.searchLob"),
            "searchSubLob" : component.get("v.searchSubLob"),
            "searchPolicyNum" : component.get("v.searchPolicyNum")
        });
        parties.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var stateParties = response.getState();
            if (stateParties === "SUCCESS") {
                //03/10/2019: George Galaios: If state success, get the returned List
                var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
                returnValue.forEach(function(record) {
                record.linkName = 'mydomainLink/'+record.CRMCustId+'/view';
            });
                //ggalaios 2019-10-08 Assign the list of Parties to the Component item
                component.set("v.data", returnValue); 
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
            } else if (stateParties == "INCOMPLETE") {
                //03/10/2019: George Galaios: If state incomplete, show message related to Internet connection
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Oops!",
                    "message": "No internet connection.",
                    type: "warning"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();

            } else if (stateParties == "ERROR") {
                //03/10/2019: George Galaios: If case of Error, return the respective message
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error!",
                    "message": "Please contact your administrator",
                    type: "error"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(parties);  
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest column type url, but since this behaviour isn't wanted you can use `lightning:navigation` and see if you can format your columns with this [behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation).

```js
({
    handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var navService = cmp.find("navService");
        // Uses the pageReference definition in the init handler
        var pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        event.preventDefault();
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my issue by making a few changes... instead of target: _blank i used _self. and in  record.linkName ='/lightning/r/'+record.CRMCustId+'/view';